# Write a LINQ query to get count on a boolean sharepoint2010 field

Tags: linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a single table:

UserName|Completed
Moran|0
Moran|1
Moran|1
Moran|0
Russ|1
Russ|1
Russ|1
James|0
James|0
James|1

I need a LINQ query (OR CAML as this is Sharepoint 2010) that will pull back the following results:

Distinct UserName & Count of 0's from the competed column.  This would show that user Moran has 2 incomplete task, Russ has none and James has 2

Moran|2
Russ|0
James|2

The following query works in SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.UserName, (select count(*) FROM AmexTransactions WHERE Completed = 0 AND UserName = a.UserName) FROM AmexTransactions a
```

I need this in either LINQ or in Sharepoint 2010 object has the data is stored in a SP2010 list.

Comment: Have you already generated the entities using SPmetal (or something else?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = dataContext.AmexTransactions
                        .GroupBy(x => x.UserName)
                        .Select(g => new
                        {
                            UserName = g.Key,
                            IncompleteTasks = g.Count(x => x.Completed == 0)
                        })
                        .ToList();
```